# How to loop a MS Word macro applying word by word in a selection?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I have a simple macro in order to insert a symbol into the front and back of a word.

```
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="a"
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Font.Color = -603914241
Selection.Font.Size = 1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="a"
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Font.Color = -603914241
Selection.Font.Size = 1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
```

Is there any way to make the macros looping through each word in the selection of text?

Comment: is this code working? what should it do? it's doing nothing for me... (add something and remove it next)...

Comment: When recording a macro, it might help to practice what you are going to do before hitting record.  From this macro, it looks like you first moved to the front of the word, added the character, changed the font and the size of the character, moved to the end of the word, moved back to the beginning, back to the end, selected the space, perhaps, and so forth.  If you are going to add VBA, I would suggest looking into the Find object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim myRangeIndex As Range
Dim myRangeStart As Range

Set myRangeStart = Selection.Range

For Each myRangeIndex In myRangeStart.Words()

   myRangeIndex.Select

   Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
   Selection.TypeText Text:="a"
   Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
   Selection.Font.Color = -603914241
   Selection.Font.Size = 1
   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
   Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
   Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
   Selection.TypeText Text:="a"
   Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
   Selection.Font.Color = -603914241
   Selection.Font.Size = 1
   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1

Next myRangeIndex
```